# Ruby On Rails authentication issue with http basic(the authentication process is triggered twice for every request)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, basic-authentication, before-filter

This is the request I send to the rails controller:

```
function login(){ 
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/myapi/show',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log(arguments);
    }
  });
 }
```

login function is used as follows:

```
<body onload='login();'>
```

This is the controller:

```
class Api::MyApi::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate
  attr_reader :user

  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
        #authenticate method checks if user with username and password exists in database
        @user = User.authenticate(username, password)
    end
  end
end
```

When I send the request, this is what's printed in the terminal:

```
Started GET "/api/myapi/show" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-15 09:42:22 +0100
Processing by Api::MyApi#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"show", "test"=>{}}
Filter chain halted as :authenticate rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/api/myapi/show" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-15 09:42:22 +0100
Processing by Api::MyApi#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"show", "test"=>{}}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`authorized` = 1 AND `users`.`verification_approved` = 1 AND `users`.`login` = 'user_login' LIMIT 1
  Location Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `locations`.* FROM `locations` WHERE `locations`.`id` = 9999 LIMIT 1
  Rendered api/myapi/show.json.rabl (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 2.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

As you can see, it tries to authenticate twice and fails the first time. It doesn't even get inside "authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic" because if I write a print statement inside the "authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic", it doesn't get printed the first time(when authentication fails), but does get printed the second time.

Things I tried:

1) When Removing the before_filter completely and just authenticating in the show method, the issue doesn't occur anymore.

2) When keeping/using the before_filter but replacing the authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic with 'true' like this:

```
def authenticate
 true
end
```

the issue doesn't occur either.

3) The issue doesn't occur when I send a request with python:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('URL_TO__RoR_Controller', auth=('username', 'password'))
print r.text
```

UPDATE:
This might be useful info: The request is sent every 10 seconds, and the credentials are sent with every request. Perhaps this has something to do with the issue.

Comment: Add `event.preventDefault()` in starting of your jquery method.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you provide the complete js/jquery method ?

Comment: See my edit(there's not much to it).

Answer (score 0):

You are sending username and password as params

AFAIK Basic auth works by setting the authorization headers

Use jQuery's beforeSend callback to add an HTTP header with the authentication information: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
},
```

The btoa() method encodes a string in base-64.

In your controller you can check the headers with

```
request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: the requests are sent by a third party .Net app, which also causes the authentication issue described in my question. I am just testing with the ajax request if the issues is caused by the third party .Net app or if it's a bug in the controller. I did try your suggestion, but it didn't work. I get the exact same output in the terminal. Also when hardcoding the username and password like this: btoa("my_username:my_password") shows a authentication popup screen.